# Cannot click on Browse button in Ruby Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**HTML:**

```
<div id="file_input_overlapped" style="position: absolute; right:0px; width: 115px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; ">
<button id="file_input_button_overlapped" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"> Browse... </button>
<input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" onchange="changeFileName(this);" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); -ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)';" type="file">
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
browse_button_element.when_visible.click
button(:browse_button, :id=> "fileToUpload")
```

It errors out saying

```
"Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError: Element not visible in 60 seconds".
```

What I tried-  I tried sending (`C:\\....` )string to the text box so we dont have to click on Browse button. But the textbox is unselectable.

Can anyone please tell me how do I click on the Browse button?  Selenium cannt find it because it is hidden?

Comment: Show how you sent path to file to `input` field. Also try `button(:browse_button, :xpath=> "(//input[@id='fileToUpload'])[2]")`

Comment: button(:browse_button, :xpath=> "(//input[@id='fileToUpload'])[2]") did not work.

Comment: choose_file_element.send_keys("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\my_file.txt") and text_field(:choose_file, :xpath=> ".//*[@id='file_name_overlapped']")

Comment: did you try : `button(:browse_button, :id=> "file_input_button_overlapped")`